# Overlay and Hover Responsiveness

Tags: hover, overlay, responsive, squarespace

I created an image overlay effect for [my portfolio page](https://www.thefirst.vc/portfolio) complete with custom CSS. It is working perfectly fine on a desktop browser but it's completely not working for mobiles. Can anyone suggest what I can do here? How can I make this responsive?

```css
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <style>
.flex-container {
    position: inherit;
    display: flex;
}

.img1-wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 280px;
    padding: 50px;
}

.image {
    width: 2000px;
}

.overlay {
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ad0909;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0%;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.img1-wrap:hover .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    }

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
 font-family: Reggae One;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reggae One' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>  
 <body>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="img1-wrap">
        <img src="/s/BBBook" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">BBBook is a community-based reading platform that facilitates collaborative study for university and school students.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
       <a href="https://www.cash.live/">
        <img src="/s/Cash-Live-Logo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Cash Live is a live-streamed, free to enter poker game show featuring daily tournaments where players compete for cash.</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
       <a href="https://codeblugames.com/">
        <img src="/s/CBG" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Code Blue Games is developing 6Degrees, a Third Person Action Adventure/Tower Defense game.</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
        <img src="/s/Acces-Job" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Accessible Jobs is developing an online job portal focused on helping people with disabilities find accessible work.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="img1-wrap">
       <a href="https://dineeasy.ca/">
      <img src="/s/dinenew" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">DineEasy is a one-stop platform for powering the digital infrastructure for restaurants, cafes, and hotels.</div>
        </div>
                         </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
                  <a href="https://www.gamejobs.ninja/" target="blank">
        <img src="/s/gamesninja.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">GameJobs.Ninja is a recruitment platform focused on the video games industry.</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
                  <a href="https://www.myhubly.com/" target="blank">
        <img src="/s/hubli" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Hubly is building technology to power the future of financial planning and advice.</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
                  <a href="https://www.ludare.com/" target="blank">
        <img src="/s/Ludare" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Ludare Games Group is a publisher of free-to-play mobile games featuring top-tier licensed intellectual properties.</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="img1-wrap">
                  <a href="https://pepper.gg/" target="blank">
        <img src="/s/pepac.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">PEPPER lets gamers and organizers discover and create local and online events for cash prizes. Acquired by TGS Esports.</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
                  <a href="https://storiiitime.com/" target="blank">
        <img src="/s/StoriiTime" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">StoriiiTime empowers online influencers to earn more with less work through its no-code narrative game templates. </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
        <img src="/s/Startup" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Startup Arena is building a model for co-working startup spaces in a post-COVID world.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
        <img src="/s/SuperCommerce" alt="Avatar" class="image">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">SuperCommerce is a buyer, operator, and scaler of ecommerce websites.
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="img1-wrap">
        <img src="/s/v2ac.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
            <a href="https://victorysquare.com/" target="blank">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">V2 Games is a developer and publisher of casual mobile games. Acquired by Victory Square Technologies.
</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img1-wrap">
        <img src="/s/Vetsie" alt="Avatar" class="image">
      <a href="https://www.vetsie.com/" target="blank">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Vetsie is making veterinary care more accessible by leveraging innovative technology to transform pet care.</div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

While avoiding detailed suggestions that would perhaps get too subjective, one could greatly improve the responsiveness of the layout by doing the following:

1. Remove all but the first `.flex-container` div. Instead, put all `.img1-wrap` elements within the first (and only) `.flex-container`.
2. Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the CSS rules for the `.flex-container` element.
3. Add `justify-content: center;` to the CSS rules for the `.flex-container` element.
4. Change the `width` CSS property from `280` to `270`.

Further improvement could certainly be made, but the above will be adequate in terms of keeping the content presentable at any width, and should serve as a basis for further customization on your part. In the above suggestions, I also did not address browser-specific prefixing for flex-related rules, which you can investigate further, if interested.